# Does lighting a match eradicate offensive odors in the bathroom or just cover them up?

Tags: smell

Perhaps we've all heard this, but if not:

There's a common belief that lighting a match after using the bathroom (in a particularly odoriferous way, mind you) will "burn up" or extinguish the fiendish fragrance.

So the skeptical question is, is it true that lighting a match snuffs the stink *(or does it just hide it)*?

Comment: [proof, if anyone questions it, that this is a belief at least held by some](http://www.kptv.com/travelgetaways/10466832/detail.html)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a [study:](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/apr99/923460606.Ch.r.html)

> When a match is struck, the first thing to burn is the head. The head of a 
>   match contains a chemical cocktail that includes a lot of sulfur. In the 
>   initial burst of combustion products there is therefore a lot of sulfur 
>   dioxide. Sulfur dioxide is an extremely pungent substance, to which the 
>   smell receptors are extremely sensitive. But it also has a very efficient 
>   numbing effect on the sense of smell. You can smell a minute amount of 
>   sulfur dioxide, but when you have done so, you will not smell anything else 
>   for a while. Sulfur dioxide is a gaseous combustion product, so if this is 
>   the main factor no-one wins the bet. It is not flame (plasma) nor smoke 
>   (solid aerosol). You can easily test this one, because if it is the main 
>   factor, other flames, like a spirit stove, a cigarette lighter, or a candle 
>   will not mask smells nearly as effectively.

Taken from [aother forum](http://ask.yahoo.com/20061109.html)

> The TV show "MythBusters" covered this topic and [concluded](http://kwc.org/mythbusters/2006/03/franklins_kite_flatulence.html)
>   that matches mask the methyl mercaptan found in flatulence and feces. So, a match may not eliminate odors, but it will push them to the background. Most of the time, that's good enough.

So, I assume it is just covered up, not burned up, as shown in the Mythbusters experiment.

Comment: can you find a chemical reaction between sulphur dioxide (or even carbon dioxide) and methyl mercaptan that can be initiated and completed in the environment of a burning match head? If so, there's at least a chance that SOME of the odorous substances would get chemically converted into something else by striking a match :)

Comment: So rather than "eradicating" or "snuffing" or "[burning off](http://www.redorbit.com/news/science/1113328777/do-matches-actually-burn-off-fart-smells-020515/)" or "[fighting](http://wendyzukerman.com/2010/03/fighting-farts-with-fire/)" or "dissipating" or "consuming" or otherwise eliminating the odor, what lighting a match really does is emit sulfur dioxide that smells so bad all by itself, that you don't care about the silly little fart smell any more. Damn!